# I get 'Error [ConfigError]: Missing region in config' each time I attempt AWS lambda function call from NodeJS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm new to AWS lambda functions and was given some sample code (below -- in the actual code I fill in the placeholders correctly, of course).  But each time I call the lambda function, I get

```
Error [ConfigError]: Missing region in config
    at Request.VALIDATE_REGION (/Users/abc/Documents/projects/bot/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:92:45)
```

Even though the region is set in `aws.config.update`.  I'm not sure what to do to fix this. I've tried removing the call to `aws.config.update`, removing the reference to `region`, but nothing helps.

I'd also be keen to know if there's a way to load the credentials from the shared file in `~/.aws/credentials`, instead of having to enter them directly here.

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');

// do this only in dev, in prod you will not need to put your keys...
aws.config.update({accessKeyId: '<YOU ACCESS KEY>', secretAccessKey: '<YOUR SECRET>', region:'ap-northeast-1'});


const lambda = new aws.Lambda();

function invokeLambda(options) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    lambda.invoke(options, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err);
      }
      return resolve(data);
    });
  });
}

const sampleCall = async () => {
  try {
    const options = {
      FunctionName: '<NAME OF THE FUNCTION YOU WANT TO INVOKE>',
      Payload: '<The JSON.stringify of the object you want to provide as parameter>',
    }
    const result = await invokeLambda(options);
    console.log(result);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};
```

Comment: why not use IAM role for lambda in dev ;)

Comment: @ArunK -- I'm new to AWS, so unclear about the difference between using credentials and IAM roles.  We've been using credential files and so it may be that we can't use IAM roles -- our access is restricted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can configure the region before using any services.

like this:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({region:'us-east-1'});
const lambda = new aws.Lambda();
```

AWS services such as lambda has the ability to assume an IAM Role. Because the applications does not need to store credentials.

here is what you should do:

- The IAM role is attached to the lambda
- Permissions are then attached to the IAM role

Basically you can attach the same policy that your IAM user is using to the IAM role. After doing that, you can remove credentials from the code.

Reference:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-create-an-aws-iam-policy-to-grant-aws-lambda-access-to-an-amazon-dynamodb-table/

Comment: Thanks.  Moving the `config` above the call to `new aws.Lambda()` solved the region issue, but now I get `security token is invalid`.  I'll talk to the administrator.

Comment: shall we try attaching permissions to the role and remove the credentials from lambda

Comment: If not, i am pretty sure that you can attach the access keys to the lambda initialization

Comment: Isn't there is a way to configure the Lambda to use a specific region without using the AWS itself. and keep it unregioned. 
Haven't found it from the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Hey No need for configure the whole AWS setttings. if you want to keep it unconfigured and not for all of your request to use the region.

The lambda constructor receive 'region' param just set it to your desired region.

Example:

```
 const lambda = new Lambda({
        region: 'us-east-1'      
 });

 lambda.invoke({ FunctionName: 'your-function-name'},
               function(err, data) {
                 if(err) { 
                    console.log(err, err.stack); 
                 }
                 else { 
                    console.log(data); 
                 }
               }
 );
```